# Name of diode depletion region voltage

Tags: voltage, diodes, depletion-region

This question is related to an electronic devices course. The unit is on diodes.

What do we call the potential difference of the electrical field across the depletion region?

Comment: This is a homework question? You may try looking at what voltages (potential differences) are usually specified for a diode.

Comment: You may call it Junction potential, built-in potential, barrier voltage etc. These are general terms and you are unlikely to get specific results in a search unless you specify some context, like 'Junction potential of a diode' etc.

Answer (score -1):

1. semiconductor junction is formed when semoconductors with p doped and n doped layers come in contact.
2. from n doped semicond. electron migrate towared p doped layer due to attraction (p means holes also migrate but has poor mobiliy.)
3. however after certain electron migration the p side becomes more negatively charged hence migration of electron reduces and after that migration may totally stop.
4. Such equillibrium forms so called depletion region and the voltage of the charges gives rise to depletion voltage.
5. such voltage depends upon the type of semiconductor.
   In case of Silicon is of the order of 0.6 to 0.7 volts.
   vtingole